# PHP- Loop through an array, and use each result as a variable in a class

Tags: php, arrays, loops, ping

So, I have a simple array called $modSites, which is just a list of urls that need to be pinged.

I loop through the array:

```
## Get array length ##

$modLength = count($modSites);

## For loop, until end of array is reached ##

for ( $i = 0; $i < $modLength; x++ );
```

But now, I want to use a php class: https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping, to ping each of the URLS, and print the results in a table. What is the most efficient way to get the values pulled from the array stuffed into a variable that I can assign to $host in the below code snippet?... so I can print the values?

```
require_once('Ping/Ping.php');
$host = 'www.example.com';
$ping = new Ping($host);
$latency = $ping->ping();
if ($latency) {
  print 'Latency is ' . $latency . ' ms';
}
else {
  print 'Host could not be reached.';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would do something like this:

```
foreach ($modSites as $site) {
  $ping = new Ping($site);
  $latency = $ping->ping();
  if ($latency) {
    print $latency;
  } else {
    print "failed.";
  }
}
```

if you wanted to build an array while you move through the foreach loop then maybe use something like this:

```
$latencyArray[$site] = $latency;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a single Ping object and just change the hosts.  You can also use a foreach loop:

```
require_once('Ping/Ping.php');
$ping = new Ping('');
foreach ($modSites as $site) {
    $ping->setHost($site);
    $latency = $ping->ping();
    if ($latency) {
      print 'Latency is ' . $latency . ' ms';
    }
    else {
      print 'Host could not be reached.';
    }
}
```